# make user input from website, database, asp.net and html-safe?

Tags: html, mysql, asp.net, database

What steps do I need to take to be sure that the input from users can't hurt my system, or any visitors system that visit the site later?

Today I only change the three following chars to ascii-code.
<,>,'

Is the system safe with these chars replaced?

I use asp.net & mysql.

The only thing I want to safe from the user input is the pure text.

(I use textfield.replace("<", "ascii-code"). is this safe?)

Thanks!

Comment: You do not have to do anything for scripting attacks, .net framework handles this for you. follow [link](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation)

Comment: I am aware of the validateRequest. But if I want to allow for example <>' as characters in string. Thats why I want to replace them with ascii.  Can ascii be dangerous or are they handled as  ordinare characters that can do no harm?

Comment: If validate request is disabled, you can use htmlencode or Use [Anti-xss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx). Would this help?